# How to I position two elements on opposite sides of a table cell

Tags: css, html-table, alignment

I have a table cell with text and an icon. I want both elements to link to the the same place. I want the text to align to the left side and the icon to align to the right side of a table cell. Code could look something like this:

```
<td><a href="#">Text<span>icon</span></a></td>
```

EDIT:
I edited the code to represent some requirements that I did not originally include. Both the text and icon must be links.

In addition, I am grabbing the width of the `<a>` tag when the user clicks on it. If I cut the text and icon into two different a tags my measurement will be inaccurate.

Comment: You mean your <a> tag?

Comment: Yes. I've edited for clarity. Thanks.

Comment: See the update to my answer. Let me know if that helps. If not, could you share a bit more about what you are trying to do? That could help us find the best approach for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chopper/66yDS/1/)?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Foobar</td>
        <td>
            <div class="left">
                <a href="#">Text</a>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <a href="#">icon</a>
            </div>
        </td>
 <table>

td {
    width: 150px;
}

.left {
    float: left;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}
```

UPDATE: How about keeping the `<a>` tag outside the `<div>`s then? Not pretty, but works: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chopper/66yDS/2/)

Comment: See new requirements above.

Answer (score 3):

The answer you accepted is far from being ideal ...!
I doubt that your HTML markup is semantically "correct" and the one shown in the answer is even worse!

One of the drawbacks of the "float solution" is, that the area between the two elements is not clickable. That means "bad usability".

And I also doubt that the "icon" is really part of the page content. Instead I believe that it is "decoration" and therefore it should be applied as background image.

So you'll get an easy solution:

```
<td><a href="#">Text</a></td>
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zT6SK/)

Comment: The icon is actually part of an icon font, thus the reason for needing to have it as an element on the page. I agree however with your useability comment.

Comment: Even in this case you could use one of the pseudo elements `::before` or `::after` to make the icon just "decoration" and not part of the content in the HTML markup. It's all about semantics ... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Assigning the CSS float property to right for the right-side span-element does the trick. As an example:

```
<td> 
    <span>left text</span>
    <span style="float: right;">right text</span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question, but it is still top of Google so decided to give an updated solution.

The current solution as of 2022 is: **Use flexbox** with `space-between`

HTML

```
<div class="oppositeEndsLine">
    <div>right side of line</div>
    <div>left side of line</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.oppositeEndsLine{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

[Adapted from this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40091515/how-to-have-two-items-on-opposite-sides-on-the-same-line)