# How to have two items on opposite sides on the same line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get two different pieces of text on opposite ends of the "page" so to speak for a mobile app.

I would like it to look like this:

```
|-----------------------------|
|DATE                  MESSAGE|
```

But on the same line.

Currently I've got it setup like this:

```
<div id="HASH" class="blue-msg">
<span id="time-HASH" class="smalltext">9 months 2 weeks ago</span>
<span class="ios-circle">MESSAGE HERE</span>
</div>
```

With the ios-circle span having `display: inline-block` set.

MESSAGE can also go on for multiple lines (like an iOS chat window), like so:

```
|-----------------------------|
|DATE                  MESSAGE|
|                      MESSAGE|
```

I don't care if the DATE text is aligned near the top of the message or near the center of the message. Either would look fine to me.

How do I do this? I would very much prefer to not use a float if possible.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Use flexbox, like this

```
#HASH {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

P.S.: If the "MESSAGE HERE" content is supposed to expand across multiple lines, I would put it in a `div` (instead of `span`) and restrict its width to 50% (adjust value as you like).

```css
#HASH {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div id="HASH" class="blue-msg">
<span id="time-HASH" class="smalltext">9 months 2 weeks ago</span>
<span class="ios-circle">MESSAGE HERE</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent, this seems to be exactly what I'm looking for! I think I've used flexbox before briefly, but it seems like I should check it out more. Appears very useful! I'll accept the answer when it lets me.

Answer (score 5):

Johannes Flexbox approach is probably the best way, but without using that, or float as you requested, you could do something like this:

```
<div id="HASH" class="blue-msg">
  <div id="left">
    <span id="time-HASH" class="smalltext">9 months 2 weeks ago</span>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <span class="ios-circle">MESSAGE HERE</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then:

```
#HASH {
  width: 100%;
}

#HASH div {
  width: 49%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ak7zxz84/

Again, I'd go with Flexbox, but this is just an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it fixed to the bottom (or another) area of the screen, why not use fixed positioning, such as:

```
#time-HASH {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
}

.ios-circle {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
display: inline-block; //if you need this

}
```