# Is there any way I can move the hamburger menu all the way to the right?

Tags: html, css

Here's the result of this piece of code:
[image]

I've tried using

```
float: right;
```

This is my html code:

```css
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@300&display=swap');

     /*COLOR SCHEME*/
     :root {
       --grey: rgb(26, 26, 26);
       --light-grey: rgb(82, 82, 82);
       --blue: #0066ff;
       --white: white;
     }

     /*BACKGROUND COLOR*/
     body {
       background-color: var(--grey);
       margin-left: 1.5em;
       margin-right: 1.5em;
     }
     
     /*---------------------------------------NAVBAR----------------------------------------*/
     .navbar {/*NAVBAR*/
       border-bottom: 1px solid var(--light-grey);
       padding: 1em;
       position: fixed;
     }
     .logo{/*KRIMAN LOGO*/
       position: relative;
       max-width: 200px;
       max-height: 200px;
     }
     span {/*THE 'MAN' IN THE KRIMAN LOGO*/
       color: var(--blue);
     }
     .logo:hover {/*THE LINK FOR THE KRIMAN LOGO*/
       cursor: pointer;
       text-decoration: none;
     }

     .menu:hover {
       cursor: pointer;
     }
     .menu {
       margin: auto 5px;
       float: right;
       width: 35px;
       height: 24.5px;
       display: inline-flex;
       margin-top: 5px;
     }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
       <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
         <title>Kriman</title>
         <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
       </head>
       <body>
         <script src="script.js"></script>
         <div class="navbar">
           <img class="logo" src="images/Kriman_Logo-Text.jpg" alt="">
           <img class="menu" src="images/menu.png" alt="menu">
         </div>
       </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: `.navbar: width: 100%; text-align: right;` as images by default are `inline-block` elements. The div doesnt span the entire width, therefor you have to change its width to span the entire available width.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have two items on opposite sides on the same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40091515/how-to-have-two-items-on-opposite-sides-on-the-same-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `width` for `.navbar`. I found `100vw-4.5em` to be a good width

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@300&display=swap');

     /*COLOR SCHEME*/
     :root {
       --grey: rgb(26, 26, 26);
       --light-grey: rgb(82, 82, 82);
       --blue: #0066ff;
       --white: white;
     }

     /*BACKGROUND COLOR*/
     body {
       background-color: var(--grey);
       margin-left: 1.5em;
       margin-right: 1.5em;
     }
     
     /*---------------------------------------NAVBAR----------------------------------------*/
     .navbar {/*NAVBAR*/
       border-bottom: 1px solid var(--light-grey);
       padding: 1em;
       position: fixed;
       width: calc(100vw - 4.5em);
     }
     .logo{/*KRIMAN LOGO*/
       position: relative;
       max-width: 200px;
       max-height: 200px;
     }
     span {/*THE 'MAN' IN THE KRIMAN LOGO*/
       color: var(--blue);
     }
     .logo:hover {/*THE LINK FOR THE KRIMAN LOGO*/
       cursor: pointer;
       text-decoration: none;
     }

     .menu:hover {
       cursor: pointer;
     }
     .menu {
       margin: auto 5px;
       float: right;
       width: 35px;
       height: 24.5px;
       display: inline-flex;
       margin-top: 5px;
     }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
       <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
         <title>Kriman</title>
         <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
       </head>
       <body>
         <script src="script.js"></script>
         <div class="navbar">
           <img class="logo" src="images/Kriman_Logo-Text.jpg" alt="">
           <img class="menu" src="images/menu.png" alt="menu">
         </div>
       </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: @MantraPatel if my answer solved your problem, I would appreciate it if you accepted it by clicking the check mark :)

Comment: Sure thing. I checked it

Answer (score 0):

To leave the logo at the left and move the hamburger icon to the far right, you can apply `display: flex; justify-content: space-between;` to the navbar, and you must set its `width` accordingly (see below - I set it at 100% minus 5em for paddings and margins):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@300&display=swap');

     /*COLOR SCHEME*/
     :root {
       --grey: rgb(26, 26, 26);
       --light-grey: rgb(82, 82, 82);
       --blue: #0066ff;
       --white: white;
     }

     /*BACKGROUND COLOR*/
     body {
       background-color: #ddd;
       margin-left: 1.5em;
       margin-right: 1.5em;
     }
     
     /*---------------------------------------NAVBAR----------------------------------------*/
     .navbar {/*NAVBAR*/
       border-bottom: 1px solid var(--light-grey);
       padding: 1em;
       position: fixed;
       width: calc(100% - 5em);
       display: flex;
       justify-content: space-between;
     }
     .logo{/*KRIMAN LOGO*/
       position: relative;
       max-width: 200px;
       max-height: 200px;
     }
     span {/*THE 'MAN' IN THE KRIMAN LOGO*/
       color: var(--blue);
     }
     .logo:hover {/*THE LINK FOR THE KRIMAN LOGO*/
       cursor: pointer;
       text-decoration: none;
     }

     .menu:hover {
       cursor: pointer;
     }
     .menu {
       margin: auto 5px;
       float: right;
       width: 35px;
       height: 24.5px;
       display: inline-flex;
       margin-top: 5px;
     }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
       <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
         <title>Kriman</title>
         <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
       </head>
       <body>
         <script src="script.js"></script>
         <div class="navbar">
           <img class="logo" src="images/Kriman_Logo-Text.jpg" alt="logo">
           <img class="menu" src="images/menu.png" alt="menu">
         </div>
       </body>
     </html>
```